# Object data being overwritten after creation

Tags: c#

I am self teaching myself C# and was hoping somebody could point out what it is that I am doing wrong. I am attempting to iterate through some XML data and create objects when I get a match.

My sequence of events are

1. Using the foreach, iterate through until i see a specific data match
2. When I see a pattern1 match clear down my lists in readiness to populate them
3. From now on everytime we see a certain pattern match update the lists
4. When I see a pattern5 match create the object with the populated lists
5. The foreach continues
6. Keep iterating through until we see a pattern1 match again
7. Repeat from step 2

My object gets created with the populated lists in Step 4 but is subsequently overwritten when we repeat in step 2.

```
class XMLData    {

    public static List<Device> Search(XElement XE)
    {
        //local variables
        bool DeviceCreated = false;
        List<Device> Devices = new List<Device>();

        string Out = "";
        List<int> List1 = new List<int>();
        List<int> List2 = new List<int>();
        List<int> List3 = new List<int>();

        IEnumerable<XElement> Logic =
        from LL in XE.Descendants("Text")
        select LL;

        foreach (XElement XML in Logic)
        {                
            //Regex Patterns
            string pattern1 = @"(?=O\()[^\)]+(?<=S)";
            string pattern2 = @"(?=O\()[^\)]+(?<=I)";
            string pattern3 = @"(?=O\()[^\)]+(?<=FA)";
            string pattern4 = @"(?=X\()[^\)]+(?<=F)";
            string pattern5 = @"(?=O\()[^\)]+(?<=L)";
            string pattern6 = @"(?=O\()[^\)]+(?<=FT).+?(?<=)";

            MatchCollection All = Common.Find(XML);

            if (Regex.Match(XML.Value, pattern1).Success)
            {
                //Clear down data ready to create a new device
                DeviceCreated = false;
                List1.Clear();
                List2.Clear();
                List3.Clear();
                List1 = Common.Find(All);                    
            }

            else if (Regex.Match(XML.Value, pattern2).Success)
            {                    
                List2 = Common.Find(All);
            }

            else if (Regex.Match(XML.Value, pattern3).Success)
            {
                List3 = Common.Find(All);
            }               

            else if (Regex.Match(XML.Value, pattern5).Success)
            {
                // create a device when we see this pattern as we should now have all of the data in the lists      
                if (!DeviceCreated)
                {
                    Devices.Add(new Device(List1, List2, List3));
                    DeviceCreated = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
        }
        return Devices;
    }

}
```

Comment: `List2 = Common.Find` and other statements like this would assign new value coming in from the `Common.Find` method. If you want to add to the list then you should do `List2.AddRange(Common.Find(All));` and same for other lists too.

Comment: Also instead of `List1.Clear();` you probably want a `new` List.  You are passing the Lists to the Device constructor.  If the Device constructor doesn't make a copy of them, you're giving the same list to every Device and then clearing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `List1 = Common.Find(All)`, `List2 = Common.Find(All)` etc, it simply overwrites the existing list.

Do an append, or in C# terms, an `AddRange()`:

```
List1.AddRange(Common.Find(All));
```